# Problem installing Unity.Mvc5 - UnityConfig.cs file is missing

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm trying to install the Unity.Mvc5 NuGet package into my project, and the readme file says to include this line in my global.asax file:

```
UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
```

It shows an error when I add that line though.  No UnityConfig.cs file was added to my solution when I installed the package.  Does anyone have any ideas as to why that's happening?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this was happening in my project, but I was able to create a new test project and copy over the UnityConfig.cs file into my working project.